# Aging buckets using MDX

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I'm tyring to create aging buckets by setting them using the logic below and although the query runs the buckets all come back blank.  I had originally used some logic that used the `lag` but found the `lag` was counting a the member level and not actual days.  What am I missing here?

```
WITH


member [0-30] as ( IIF (Datediff("d", [TXN].[Age Date], STRTOMEMBER(@ToDOSDate,CONSTRAINED) ) >=0 AND Datediff("d", [TXN].[Age Date], STRTOMEMBER(@ToDOSDate,CONSTRAINED) ) <= 30
 , [measures].[charge_amount] , 0) 
)

member [31-60] as ( IIF(Datediff('d', [TXN].[Age Date], STRTOMEMBER(@ToDOSDate,CONSTRAINED) ) >=31 AND Datediff('d', [TXN].[Age Date], STRTOMEMBER(@ToDOSDate,CONSTRAINED) ) <= 60 
,[measures].[charge_amount], 0 ) 
)

member [61-90] as ( IIF(Datediff("d", [TXN].[Age Date], STRTOMEMBER(@ToDOSDate,CONSTRAINED) ) >=61 AND Datediff("d", [TXN].[Age Date], STRTOMEMBER(@ToDOSDate,CONSTRAINED) ) <= 90 
,[measures].[charge_amount], 0 ) 
)

member [91-120] as ( IIF(Datediff("d", [TXN].[Age Date], STRTOMEMBER(@ToDOSDate,CONSTRAINED) ) >=91 AND Datediff("d", [TXN].[Age Date], STRTOMEMBER(@ToDOSDate,CONSTRAINED) ) <= 120 
,[measures].[charge_amount], 0 ) 
)

member [120+] as ( IIF(Datediff("d", [TXN].Age Date], STRTOMEMBER(@ToDOSDate,CONSTRAINED) ) >= 120 
,[measures].[ charge_amount], 0 ) 
)
```

Comment: Not that this will fix it, but the last statement should be > 120. You are already including 120 in the 91-120 statement. Also, what is the datatype of @ToDOSDate?

Comment: @WEI_DBA thanks? :)

Comment: You have double quotes and single quote around the d in your DateDiff. remove that and put in the word Day.

Comment: The quotes were the result of some experimenting.  I tried what you suggested but no difference.

Comment: Try hard coding a date in and see if you get results. Preferably a date that will get results. :-)

Comment: also not working with hard coded date.  thinking this approach is just incorrect.

Comment: Datediff will find the difference between two dates - but you're feeding in two members. Is `[TXN].[Age Date]` in your `SELECT` clause?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume:

1. You have `[TXN].[Age Date]` ON ROWS, in your `SELECT` clause.
2. That `@ToDOSDate` is correct and you have fully tested that it is working when fed into `STRTOMEMBER(@ToDOSDate,CONSTRAINED)`.

`Datediff` is a vba function and requires *date* typed data as it's arguments - you are feeding in data that is of type *member*.

A further assumption I'll make is that the `Name` attribute of members of the hierarchy `[TXN].[Age Date]` are formatted in such a way as to be interpretted as dates. You could then do the following:

```
WITH
  MEMBER [Measures].[0-30] AS 
      IIF (
       Datediff(
          "d" 
         ,[TXN].[Age Date].CURRENTMEMBER.NAME
         ,STRTOMEMBER(@ToDOSDate,CONSTRAINED).NAME 
       ) >=0 
       AND 
       Datediff(
          "d"
         ,[TXN].[Age Date].CURRENTMEMBER.NAME
         ,STRTOMEMBER(@ToDOSDate,CONSTRAINED).NAME  
       ) <= 30
    , [measures].[charge_amount] 
    , NULL)
```